# reemplazar simbolo " por palabra Pulgadas en update de php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo en una base de datos en una tabla llamada descripcion_prov tipo TEXT, dentro de su contenido texto hay un simbolo de " (pulgadas) que deseo reemplazar por una palabra (Pul.) y tengo este update con una condicion:

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_EXPORT . " set descripcion_prov = str_replace(['"', 'Pul.']) where precio_compra <> '0.00'");
```

Necesito que el simbolo de " sea reemplazado por la palabra Pul. pero este simbolo es un caracter reservado de mysql

me da error el update:

EJEMPLO:

el campo contiene este texto:

**Tele 25" color**

y necesito reemplazar por:

**Tele 25 Pul. color**

Comment: Has probado con `\"`?

Comment: debería servir: `tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_EXPORT . " set descripcion_prov = str_replace(['\"', 'Pul.']) where precio_compra <> '0.00'");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de lanzar la query, cambia el valor con la funcion `str_replace` así:

```
str_replace(TEXTO_BUSCADO,VALOR_QUE_TENDRA,DONDE_LO_BUSCO);
```

Despues puedes lanzar la query normalmente.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar `\` para escapar el carácter `"` para evitar el error de `mysql`

Cambia:

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_EXPORT . " set descripcion_prov = str_replace(['"', 'Pul.']) where precio_compra <> '0.00'");
```

Por:

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE_EXPORT . " set descripcion_prov = str_replace(['\"', 'Pul.']) where precio_compra <> '0.00'");
```

También puedes utilizar la función de `PHP` [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) para *escapar* caracteres especiales.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$sql = "update " . TABLE_EXPORT . " set descripcion_prov = str_replace(['"', 'Pul.']) where precio_compra <> '0.00'";

$sqlEscapda = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $sql);

tep_db_query($sqlEscapda);
```

**Nota:** `$link` seria la variable donde se almacena la conexión a la `BD`.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$link= mysqli_connect("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_BBDD");
```

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '['"', 'Pul.']) where precio_compra <> '0.00'' at line 1

update export_table set descripcion_prov = str_replace(['"', 'Pul.']) where precio_compra <> '0.00'